# How to stop listing to audio in browser with navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audio-recording, navigator

I am recording audio from browser with  help of navigator.getUserMedia, my code is

```
   if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        if (!navigator.cancelAnimationFrame)
            navigator.cancelAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || navigator.mozCancelAnimationFrame;
        if (!navigator.requestAnimationFrame)
            navigator.requestAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || navigator.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            },
        }, gotStream, function(e) {
            alert('Error getting audio');
            console.log(e);
        });
```

**it works fine,but my probable is i want to stop listing browser audio after some time ,how i can do it ?**

Comment: how about `stream.stop()`

Comment: yes stream.stop() worked